# How to prevent vertical space of empty arguments

Tags: spacing

Here is an updated version of my earlier (perhaps, unnecessarily complex) question:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\newenvironment{customminipage}
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}}
  {\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{6ex}\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[3]{
{\begin{customminipage}#1\end{customminipage}}
{\begin{customminipage}#2\end{customminipage}}
{\begin{customminipage}#3\end{customminipage}}
}

\begin{document}
Some text

\mynewcommand
{}
{}
{Argument 3}

Some text
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

What am I supposed to do (perhaps `minipage` approach is not the optimal approach) to prevent the vertical spacing of empty arguments?

Comment: You want to prevent empty minipages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\notblank{#1}{true branch}{false branch}` from `etoolbox` to test for empty arguments first before using brute force `minipage` environments which add vertical space regardless whether some text is to be inserted nor not.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\newenvironment{customminipage}
{\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}}
  {\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{6ex}\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[3]{%
  \notblank{#1}{\begin{customminipage}#1\end{customminipage}}{}%
  \notblank{#2}{\begin{customminipage}#2\end{customminipage}}{}%
  \notblank{#3}{\begin{customminipage}#3\end{customminipage}}{}%
}

\begin{document}
Some text

\mynewcommand
{}
{}
{Argument 3}

\mynewcommand
{And now}
{for something completely different}
{Argument 3}


Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As expected, I did not know `\notblank`.

Comment: @blackened: No problem, I did not know 18 months ago too... there's a similar command `\ifblank{}` which tests for blank arguments first.

Comment: How does `\ifblank` work for the following scenario: Suppose the `customminipage` environment has both top and bottom vertical spaces. But, if there are two consecutive non-blank arguments, the bottom margin of one argument shall not be added to the top margin of the next argument.

Comment: @blackened: Short answer: I doubt that `customminipage` is the correct tool for this. I'll think about it but it's a new question